# yii ActiveRecord always querying database

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii, models

Using Yii 1 and ActiveRecord -
I'm pretty new in both.

```
$types = CasinoSgTypes::model();
$types->findAll();
$types->findByPk(3);
```

I thought Yii AR will try to search in recently received data first instead of that I've got 2 calls to the database. Probably I'm using it in a wrong way?

sure i can walk through the array of results received by the first query (findAll) manually, but I'd like to do this by means of AR.

in other words is there a way to force AR search inside already received data and only then ask the database or smth like this. how to use AR+Yii models in a right way to avoid unnecessary queries ?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `$types->findAll();` the data isn't saved in the AR class and as such you cannot search using it. An easier alternative to searching in the data is to use [query caching](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.data#query-caching):

```
$types->cache(3600)->findByPk(3);
```

Comment: so neither AR nor model have kind of state ? to accumulate some data and reduce database load ? may be they do have im just using in a wrong way ?